# Dates not displaying on X Axis using Chart.Js on MVC 5

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, chart.js

My Line chart using Chart.js is nost displaying the dates on X Axis.  the dates can be seen on debug mode (coming from Json Controller). The Y axis is fine.
see my chart: https://gyazo.com/96c992818ce575ac30c59622ed542acf .

it supposed to display cases like:

1) branch2 Count = 1, startDate = '2019-10-02'

2) branch2 Count = 1, startDate = '2019-09-30'

I have tried the examples provided by stackoverflow without success.

```
var dataChart = {
           label: [],
           datasets: [
               {
                   label: "Branch1",
                   backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.31)",
                   borderColor: "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.66)",
                   pointBorderColor: "rgba(0, 0, 255,0.70)",
                   pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 255,0.70)",
                   pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                   pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)",
                   pointBorderWidth: "1",
                   data: []
               },
               {
                   label: "Branch2",
                   backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 128, 128, 0.31)",
                   borderColor: "rgba(255, 128, 128, 0.66)",
                   pointBorderColor: "rgba(255, 128, 128,0.70)",
                   pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(255, 128, 128,0.70)",
                   pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                   pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(255, 128, 128, 1)",
                   pointBorderWidth: "1",
                   data: []
               },
               {
                   label: "Branch3",
                   backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 204, 153, 0.31)",
                   borderColor: "rgba(0, 204, 153, 0.66)",
                   pointBorderColor: "rgba(0, 204, 153,0.70)",
                   pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(0, 204, 153,0.70)",
                   pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                   pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(0, 204, 153, 1)",
                   pointBorderWidth: "1",
                   data: []
               }
           ]
       };

       $.getJSON("TreasuryChart/",
           function(branchData) {
               for (var i = 0; i < branchData.length; i++) {
                   var d = moment(branchData[i].startDate);
                   dataChart.label.push(d);
                   dataChart.datasets[0].data.push(branchData[i].branch1);
                   dataChart.datasets[1].data.push(branchData[i].branch2);
                   dataChart.datasets[2].data.push(branchData[i].branch3);
               }
               var ctx = document.getElementById("TreasuryChart").getContext("2d");
               var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx,
                   {
                       type: "line",
                       data: dataChart,
                       options: {
                           responsive: true,
                           maintainAspectRatio: false,
                           scales: {
                               xAxis: [
                                   {
                                       //display: true,
                                       type: 'time',
                                       time: {
                                           parser: 'MMM D',
                                           unit: 'day',
                                           displayFormats: {
                                               day: 'MMM D'
                                           }
                                       },
                                       ticks: {
                                         source: 'dataChart'
                                       }
                                   }
                               ],
                               yAxes: [
                                   {
                                       ticks: {
                                           beginAtZero: true
                                       }
                                   }
                               ]
                           }
                       }
                   });
           });
```

I expect to display the chart with its dates on the X Axis on format Day Month.

Thanks an advance for your help.

Comment: It is `xAxes`, not `xAxis`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple spelling mistake. It's `xAxes` not `xAxis`. (And I set scaleLabel to `display: true`, because I don't know, what Chart.js version you using)

```
scales: {
   xAxes: [
       {
           //display: true,
           type: 'time',
           time: {
               parser: 'MMM D',
               unit: 'day',
               displayFormats: {
                   day: 'MMM D'
               }
           },
           ticks: {
             source: 'dataChart'
           },
           scaleLabel: {
              display: true
           }
       }
   ],
   yAxes: [
       {
           ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true
           },
           scaleLabel: {
             display: true
           }
       }
   ]
```

}

Comment: Thanks guys for the response, sorry it was my bad.  Also I have misspelled the array label [ ] , which should be labels [ ] instead.  Thanks for the support, it is working now.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Mispellings can give you a hard time. Solving your problems yourself, good job! I hope, we can help you next time. :)